# Constantly getting undefined when iterating through an array

Tags: javascript, reactjs, redux

So I'm just practising my react redux skills. Im a beginner. I have created an action, reducer and several components. I'm basically making a todo app. I am fetching the data from an API which I have successfully done but the problem is arising when I'm trying to loop through the data and have it surrounded with `<li>` tags. I am getting `Cannot read property 'map' of undefined` which i dont understand why because in the console i can clearly see the array.

Action:

```
export function getLists(){
return function (dispatch) {
    return fetch ("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1")
    .then( response => response.json())
    .then (json => {console.log('sdsd'); console.log(json);
        dispatch({  type: "ADD_ITEMS", payload: { json, loading: false}  });
    });
}
}
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
todothings: [],
loading: true
};
function rootReducer (state = initialState, action) {
    if( action.type === "ADD_ITEMS"){
        console.dir("In the ADD_ITEMS reducer" + action.payload);
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            todothings: state.todothings.concat(action.payload.json),
            loading: action.payload.loading,
          });
    } else if ( action.type === "DELETE_ITEM") {
    } else {
        return state;
    }
} 
export default rootReducer;
```

ToDo Components:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getLists } from '../actions/index';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import TodoItems from './TodoItems';

class TodosComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('in the Todos comp -> componentDidMount()');
        this.props.getList();
    }
    render(){
        const {todothings , loading} = this.props;
        if(!loading){ 
            return(
                <div>  
                    <p>dfd</p>
                    {console.log(todothings)}
                    <TodoItems list={todothings}></TodoItems>
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <p>Fetching from upstream.</p>
            )
        }
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {        
        todothings: state.todothings,
        loading: state.loading,
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
        getList: () => dispatch(getLists())
      };
}
const Todos = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodosComponent)
export default Todos;
```

TodoItem Component:

```
import React from 'react';

function TodoItems (props) {
    return(
        <div>
            <ul>
            {console.log('In the todoitems')}
            {console.log(props)}

            {props.list.map( element => (
               <p>{element.data}</p>
            ))}
            </ul>
        </div>
    );
}

export default TodoItems;
```

EDIT:

This is what I have so far now:

ToDoItems:

```
import React from 'react';

const TodoItems = ({ list = [] }) => {
    if (list.length === 0) return null;
    return (
      <ul>
        {list.map(item => (
          <li key={item.id} {...item}>
            <p>{item.first_name}</p>
          </li>
        ))}
      </ul>
    );
  };
export default TodoItems;
```

ToDo Component:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { getLists } from '../actions/index';
import { connect } from 'react-redux';
import TodoItems from './TodoItems';

class TodosComponent extends Component {
    componentDidMount(){
        console.log('in the Todos comp -> componentDidMount()');
        this.props.getList();
    }
    render(){
        const {todothings , loading} = this.props;
        if(!loading){ 
            return(
                <div>  
                    <p>dfd</p>
                    {console.log('in the todo comp')}
                    {console.log(todothings)}
                    <TodoItems list={todothings.data}></TodoItems>
                </div>
            )
        } else {
            return (
                <p>Fetching from upstream.</p>
            )
        }
    }
}

function mapStateToProps(state){
    return {        
        todothings: state.todothings,
        loading: state.loading,
    }
}
function mapDispatchToProps(dispatch){
    return {
        getList: () => dispatch(getLists())
      };
}
const Todos = connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(TodosComponent)
export default Todos;
```

Reducer:

```
const initialState = {
todothings: [],
loading: true
};

function rootReducer (state = initialState, action) {
    if( action.type === "ADD_ITEMS"){
        console.dir("In the ADD_ITEMS reducer" + action.payload);
        return Object.assign({}, state, {
            todothings: state.todothings.concat(action.payload.json.data),
            loading: action.payload.loading,
          });
    } else if ( action.type === "DELETE_ITEM") {
    } else {
        return state;
    }
} 
export default rootReducer;
```

Action:

```
export function getLists(){
return function (dispatch) {
    return fetch ("https://reqres.in/api/users?page=1")
    .then( response => response.json())
    .then (json => {console.log('sdsd'); console.log(json);
        dispatch({  type: "ADD_ITEMS", payload: { json, loading: false}  

});
        });
    }
}
```

There are now no errors yet nothing is getting displayed:

```
(3) [{…}, {…}, {…}]
0: {id: 1, email: "george.bluth@reqres.in", first_name: "George", last_name: "Bluth", avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/calebogden/128.jpg"}
1: {id: 2, email: "janet.weaver@reqres.in", first_name: "Janet", last_name: "Weaver", avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/josephstein/128.jpg"}
2: {id: 3, email: "emma.wong@reqres.in", first_name: "Emma", last_name: "Wong", avatar: "https://s3.amazonaws.com/uifaces/faces/twitter/olegpogodaev/128.jpg"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
```

Comment: Which `console.log` are you getting the data from? You have 5 logs in your code above.

Comment: from the `ToDoItem` component, the log is `list: Array(1)
0:
data: Array(3)
0: {id: 1, email: "g.buth@reqres.in", first_name: "George", last_name: "Bluth"}
1: {id: 2, email: "janet.weaver@reqres.in", first_name: "Janet", last_name: "Weaver"}
2: {id: 3, email: "emma.wong@reqres.in", first_name: "Emma", last_name: "Wong"}
length: 3
__proto__: Array(0)
page: 1
per_page: 3
total: 12
total_pages: 4
__proto__: Object
length: 1
__proto__: Array(0)
__proto__: Object`

Answer (score 0):

Afternoon,

I think the data you want is from `prop.list.data` not `props.list` within `<TodoItems />`

In your component `<TodDo />` try:

```
<TodoItems list={todothings.data}></TodoItems>
```

Then tidy up your stateless component `<TodoItems />` (to cover an empty array):

```
const TodoItems = ({ list = [] }) => {
  if (list.length === 0) return null;

  return (
    <ul>
      {list.map(item => (
        <li key={item.id} {...item}>
          <ul>
            {Object.keys(item).map((data, key) => (
              <li {...{ key }}>{data}</li>
            ))}
          </ul>
        </li>
      ))}
    </ul>
  );
};
```

Note:

Your array has an object, with this shape:

```
{
    id: 1,
    email: "g.buth@reqres.in",
    first_name: "George",
    last_name: "Bluth"
}
```

What do you want to return in your `<li>`?

Update to loop through object.

Comment: Thanks for replying. I'll try that now. I just want to concat all their details and output them on each llist.

Comment: Hmm, im getting undefined `TypeError: Cannot read property 'length' of undefined` on the part where im checking if the array is empty

Comment: Can you update (at the bottom of the question) the json response please. Rather than console copy.

Comment: Since list has a default arg of an empty array it can't but undefined. As it is defined on mount. Did you copy the copy over correctly?

Comment: It was undefined since I pasted it wrong. I've correctly pasted it and now theres no error but theres no list output on the page (despite the being populated based on the console output)

Comment: So now it sounds like your hitting that condition where your list is empty (this saves rendering an empty `<ul>`. Try using this <pre>{JSON.stringify({YOUR_DATA}, null, 2)</pre>. To test your data reaches `<ToDo />`.